# google sitemap generator : only the default hostname is listed

Tags: google, sitemap

I successfuly installed the google sitemap generator on a kimsufi server, running on debian with apache2.2.  But when I go to http://example.com:8181, only the default hostname is listed, so I can't configure the other hosted website.

I installed the google sitemap generator by following [this instruction](http://googlesitemapgenerator.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/gsg-installation.html) and with this command line:

```
./install.sh -g www-data.
```

After a succeeded install, I use this command to be able to go in the admin page :

```
usr/local/google-sitemap-generator/bin/sitemap-daemon remote_admin enable.
```

The other hostnames was configured manually, in the bind9 and apache2/sites-enabled config file. Why they don't appear?